# JQuery accordion, run function after accordion fully loaded

Tags: jquery, accordion

I am trying to retrieve/manipulate an elements offset when the page loads. I can do this, but what I have currently runs before the JQuery accordion is fully loaded, so after I change the offset, the accordion than initializes, and then changes the elements positions inside of it.

So how can I go about running my function after the accordion has been fully loaded?

```
$("#accordion").accordion({
    active: false,
    collapsible: true,
    heightStyle: 'content'
});



$(".form-element").each(function(){
        var ot = $(this).offset().top;
        var ol = $(this).offset().left;

        var got = Math.round(ot / 10) * 10;
        var gol = Math.round(ol / 10) * 10;

        $(this).offset({ top: got, left: gol })
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#accordion").accordion({
    active: false,
    collapsible: true,
    heightStyle: 'content',
    create: function( event, ui ) {doMyForm();}
});

function doMyForm(){
    $(".form-element").each(function(){
        var ot = $(this).offset().top;
        var ol = $(this).offset().left;

        var got = Math.round(ot / 10) * 10;
        var gol = Math.round(ol / 10) * 10;

        $(this).offset({ top: got, left: gol })
    });
}
```

Comment: Works great thanks, also would you happen to know how I can run the doMyForm() function everytime a drop down is clicked in the accordion?

Comment: well if by `drop down` you mean a `select` then you could do somthing like this `$('#accordion').on('click, 'select', function(){doMyForm();})`  I have `delegated` the selector here in case you add the `select` inputs dynamically after the listener (my previous line of code) is added.